# How to solve problem with Terrain Flashing and then disappears when flying away?

Tags: unity, terrain, resolution, terrain-rendering

I am making flight simulator( my first Unity project) , the biggest challenge so far is terrain, so whenever I fly away from it (not that far) the terrain starts flashing and disappears which is just green mountains, so when i come back to it, i have no idea where its position is, but it suddenly appears (again flashing) when I am close , the terrain size is normal but it's on top of a huge other terrain (about 100,000 * 100,000 which is the max),I tried changing pixel error and base map distance, no change, I looked at big terrain solutions online, but non of them really helped me, Any advice? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your near and far values are to far apart. Could you share a gif or video of it?

Comment: As Vallentin said, the issue might be caused by how you setup your far and near planes.

Comment: I don’t know anything about unity, but it sounds like you could use a logarithmic depth buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I asked this question, I remember that I found a solution (may or may not work for you), and wanted to share it anyway.

None of the intensity number setting worked for me, what I ended up doing is that since I originally have the terrain on top of the ocean (a large radius body of water that I put), the ocean ends up appearing at high altitude and the terrain disappears, the solution is to simply not place the terrain over water, so I had four bodies of water intersecting at the for edges of my terrain instead of one body of water where the terrain sits, therefore there is nothing below the terrain, it doesn't flash or disappear at higher altitude anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've seen(though it may not work well for a flight simulator) I've seen with messed up terrain in the distance is to add a fog, to mask the messed up terrain in the disatnce. Go to lighting tab, and it should be close to the bottom of the lighting tab. You simply click it on, though make sure it's intensedy is super low(0.001) so what the player sees isn't just a bunch of fog when flying. I hope this helped in making the essed up terrain invisible.

Comment: good idea, but the issue remains.I tried your idea too.